# Every new file based on .xlt template should have code in it

Tags: excel, vba, templates

I have software that uses an .xlt template to create reports in .xls.

My goal is that every newly created report.xls would have that code in it and send some data to a masterlist.

`Set From = Workbooks("path to the .xlt").Worksheets("bla")` won't work.

I have Excel 365.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Add("path to the .xlt")  ' add new workbook from template
wb.SaveAs Filename:=<filename>, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Select file format from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat